# Occasional deadlock when keyboard input in WKWebview

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

This has been a problem in our apps for a long time, and it's gotten worse with the release of iOS17. Here's the call stack,is there any clue to solve it?

```
___psynch_cvwait
__pthread_cond_wait
-[NSCondition waitUntilDate:]
-[NSConditionLock lockWhenCondition:beforeDate:]
-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue lockWhenReadyForMainThread]
-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilTaskIsFinished:]
-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performSingleTask:]
-[UIKeyboardImpl generateAutocorrectionReplacements:]
-[UITextReplacementGeneratorForCorrections addAutocorrectionGuessesToReplacements:]
-[UITextReplacementGeneratorForCorrections replacements]
-[UIWKTextInteractionAssistant showReplacementsForText:withOptions:rects:]
___68-[UIWKTextInteractionAssistant showReplacementsForText:withOptions:]_block_invoke_2
_ZN3WTF6Detail15CallableWrapperIZ80-[WKContentView(WKInteraction) requestTextRectsForString:withCompletionHandler:]E5$_105vJRKNS_6VectorIN7WebCore9FloatRectELm0ENS_15CrashOnOverflowELm16ENS_10FastMallocEEEEE4callESA_
WTF::Function<void (WebKit::WebAutocorrectionData)>::operator()(WebKit::WebAutocorrectionData) const
WTF::CompletionHandler<void (WebKit::WebAutocorrectionData)>::operator()(WebKit::WebAutocorrectionData)
WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<IPC::Connection::makeAsyncReplyHandler<Messages::WebPage::RequestAutocorrectionData, WTF::CompletionHandler<void (WebKit::WebAutocorrectionData)> >(WTF::CompletionHandler<void (WebKit::WebAutocorrectionData)>&&, WTF::ThreadLikeAssertion)::{lambda(IPC::Decoder*)#1}, void, IPC::Decoder*>::call(IPC::Decoder*)
WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WebKit::AuxiliaryProcessProxy::sendMessage(WTF::UniqueRef<IPC::Encoder>&&, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendOption>, std::__1::optional<IPC::ConnectionAsyncReplyHandler>, WebKit::AuxiliaryProcessProxy::ShouldStartProcessThrottlerActivity)::$_1, void, IPC::Decoder*>::call(IPC::Decoder*)
IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Decoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Decoder> >)
IPC::Connection::dispatchIncomingMessages()
WTF::RunLoop::performWork()
WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*)
___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
___CFRunLoopDoSource0
___CFRunLoopDoSources0
___CFRunLoopRun
_CFRunLoopRunSpecific
_GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
_UIApplicationMain
main    main.m:69
start
```

I found some people say that set input 'autocorrect=off' may fix this problem, but I've tried it and it doesn't work very well. Is there any other solution?